# Using 2048 bit primes in JSch

Tags: java, encryption, ssh, cryptography, jsch

I am trying to attempt SSH connection from my Java application to an external server of client. The client has enhanced the security and they are not accepting 1024 bit primes but my JSch is sending only 1024 bit primes.

Please find verbose error output from my application below:

```
INFO  |: Launching [sftp] handler
INFO  |: Creating SFTP session to host [server1] with logger for JSch
INFO  |: Connecting via public/private key.
INFO  |: Session created.
INFO  |: Connecting to server1 port 22
INFO  |: Connection established
INFO  |: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-VShell_4_1_1_862 VShell
INFO  |: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.53
INFO  |: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO  |: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO  |: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO  |: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO  |: kex: server: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
INFO  |: kex: server: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
INFO  |: kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
INFO  |: kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
INFO  |: kex: server: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1
INFO  |: kex: server: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1
INFO  |: kex: server: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
INFO  |: kex: server: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
INFO  |: kex: client: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO  |: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
INFO  |: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO  |: kex: client: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
INFO  |: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO  |: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO  |: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
INFO  |: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
INFO  |: SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<1024) sent
INFO  |: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
INFO  |: Disconnecting from server1 port 22
ERROR |: Unable to connect to SFTP server. com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 11 No appropriate prime between 1024 and 1024 is available.  en
INFO  |: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Few other blogs suggested upgrading to JSch version 0.1.53 would fix the issue but I am already using 0.1.53 version in my application.

When I try to connect from command line using verbose option I am able to connect:

```
$ sftp -v username@server1
Connecting to server1...
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server1 [10.XX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version VShell_4_1_1_862 VShell
debug1: no match: VShell_4_1_1_862 VShell
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'server1' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /.ssh/known_hosts:155
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
sftp>
```

Note: I am using SSH-2 RSA 2048 bit keys for connectivity using my application and in command line as well. The only difference I could observe using my application and command line is:

My application is sending the below information when connecting:

```
INFO  |: SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<1024) sent
```

Whereas command line connectivity is sending below information when connecting:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
```

Any suggestion on how to change my application to send SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) would be much helpful.

Answer (score 5):

See [JSch change log](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ChangeLog) for *"Changes since version 0.1.52"*:

> - change: Logjam: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 and
>   diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 will use 2048-bit key on
>   Java8's SunJCE, thanks to JDK-6521495 and JDK-7044060.

So you are correct that you need JSch 0.1.53, but you also need these fixes in your JDK:

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6521495
- https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7044060